# psycopg creata database failed，syntax error

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I used psycopg2 to create a database failure, grammatical mistakes, but in the first few lines using the same grammar is the work, why ask? Two lines of code, why is the second line of grammatical mistakes?

[code]

```
db_name = 'series_id'
self._cur_root.execute("CREATE DATABASE '%s' owner %s ;" % (db_name, self.username))
```

[error]

```
syntax error at or near "'series_id'"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE 'series_id' owner postgres ;
```

Comment: Are you sure you need quotes around the database name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code, remove cotes from %s:

```
self._cur_root.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s owner %s ;" % (db_name, self.username))
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL uses single quotes for strings and double for literals and names that could be misparsed or contain capital letters.  If you need to quote a name  try:

```
 ' CREATE DATABASE "%s" OWNER "%s"; '  % ....
```

Here you render your request manually.   Generally it's better to use DB driver's function to substitute values - they make proper quotation and prevents SQL injections.